# Do the Substrate have terminal CLI tools like Ethereum attach?

Tags: substrate

The only interactive tool I knew is a front-end UI from The substrate tutorials. I want to know if there are some terminal CLI tools like Geth attach?

It can help me:

- query chain state, block number, block info, transaction info...
- send transaction

Comment: This may be helpful https://github.com/polkadot-js/tools

Comment: Okay, Thank you.